# Google Local Home SDK submission

Tags: google-smart-home

I have completed the local home development for an action but I can’t find a way to upload the code snippet through the console and update our existing production action. I have tested it locally with our devices and it's working but its really not clear what to do next with regards to submitting the snippet and then updating the smart home action. What is the next stage to get a local home action implementation submitted?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The [Local Home SDK](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/concepts/local) is currently in developer preview, so we are not accepting submissions for production at this time. We will update the [developer guides](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/local) with more details on submission and certification once we exit preview with the first stable release.